# rewrite existing file so that it gets replaced by new version atomically, only once fully written

Tags: kernel, open-files

I vaguely recall reading somewhere that there used to be, in some Unices a way to open an existing file for writing, with a flag that asked the kernel to use the old version (for other processes accessing it for reading), until the "new" version was fully written (fd closed), from which point the file appeared as the new version.

In another words, other processes either saw the old version, or the new one,  never an incompletely-written one.

Can someone knowledgeable point me to a reference?

Comment: Sounds like what [Plan 9](http://cm.bell-labs.com/magic/man2html/2/open) might do, but no.

Comment: Sounds like [Files-11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files-11) on OpenVMS: "Every time a file is saved, rather than overwriting the existing version, a new file with the same name but an incremented version number is created."

Comment: Why did you ask? Do you need that functionality, or was it just curiosity?

Comment: I would be happy to have that functionality, and I recalled reading somewhere that it existed. So a mixture of both need and curiosity.

Comment: All Unix systems allow this in another manner - create new file in the same directory, fill with changed contents and do atomic rename. This is much more expensive for small changes but working.

Comment: @Netch this is not the same: you need a temporary file with a name, and for some time that would be visible on the filesystem. If the process gets interrupted in that interval the temporary file would be left there.

Answer (score 15):

What you're describing sounds exactly like a basic rename to overwrite a file.

When you rename/move one file on top of another, the old file is unlinked. Meaning the file still exists, but it isn't in the filesystem tree any more. Thus old applications will continue to be able to access the file as long as they keep it open. Once all applications have closed the old file, then its actually unallocated on the disk.

The `rename` system call is an atomic operation. So to do this you would create a new file under a different name, and then call `rename` to rename the temporary file as the one you want to replace. Since the operation is atomic, there is absolutely no period where the file is missing. It instantly goes from old file to new file.
Note though that the temporary file and the file being replaced have to reside on the same mount point.

Comment: You only can use that if your program is specifically written with the functionality in mind. In this case, however, it was an OS feature, whence even regular programs were given this atomical semantics automatically.

Comment: @eudoxos your comment makes no sense. Youre saying programs would have to be written specifically to do the `rename` swap thing. Even if such a 'OS feature' as youre talking about existed, the program would still have to be written to take advantage of that as well. Whats the difference?

Comment: There is a difference if you pass a (possibly unsupported) flag to the `open` syscall or if you have to do what you describe by hand.

Comment: Keep in mind that for keeping either the old or the fully written new version in case of a crash you need to additionally sync the new file to disk with fsync or similar

Comment: @textshell without the sync you still get atomicity though .... just not durability ... correct? I don't understand the argument at https://goo.gl/qfQQfy in this case. In my case I have a system under extreme load and I want to avoid file system flushes and I don't care if the file survives a crash.

Comment: @wcochran Without the fsync the file can end up in a state that is neither the old nor the new content on a crash. Thus i wouldn't call it atomic. One way this can happen if the inode and directory changes are flushed out to disk before the actual content of the new file is flushed. Then the file might read back as empty or even as a file with the correct size but just filled with zero bytes. This actually is a real problem in some configurations where people lost data because neither the old nor the new version was available after after a crash.

Comment: @textshell but that's durability .... the files I am writing out are meaningless if the system crashes. I just want to make sure readers don't get don't get a partially written file while the system is running.

Comment: @wcochran Wikipedia disagrees in the definition of atomic """An atomic system must guarantee atomicity in each and every situation, including power failures, errors and crashes.""" [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID]. If you don't care about what happens after crashes you should never need to fsync anything.

Answer (score 8):

As [Patrick writes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35289/21416), the usual way to do this is to write the new version to a separate file, and when finished rename the new version to the old filename, overwriting it atomically. This second operation is called *overwrite-by-rename*.

#### Now, some references:

- ISO C requires `rename` to be atomic. [From the Open Group Base Specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html):

  > If the link named by the *new* argument exists, it shall be removed and *old* renamed to
  >   *new*. In this case, a link named *new* shall remain visible to other processes throughout the renaming operation and
  >   refer either to the file referred to by *new* or *old* before the operation began.
- [Old versions of Mac OS X did not have atomic renames; this is reportedly fixed in Lion.](http://www.weirdnet.nl/apple/rename.html)
- Btrfs apparently intentionally violates the standard by [not guaranteeing atomic renames](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php?title=FAQ&oldid=11521#What_are_the_crash_guarantees_of_rename.3F), for performance reasons. However, [overwrite-by-rename is still atomic](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php?title=FAQ&oldid=11521#What_are_the_crash_guarantees_of_overwrite-by-rename.3F), which is all you need for this purpose.

Comment: `man 3p rename` tells me that `rename` is indeed atomic, and I guess that's meant for all Linux file systems. And when I read the first article that you linked, I still think that Btrfs rename operations are atomic.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of [Allocate On Flush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocate-on-flush). When a filesystem uses this feature, instead of writing data directly to disk, it subtracts the size of the data to be written from the disk's free space counter, and holds the data in memory until it a sync system call is performed or the kernel decides to flush the dirty buffers.

In this case, if the file is being modified by one process, and gets opened by another process, the latter process will "see" the unmodified (*or "old" if you prefer*) version of the file.

Of course, the above are theoretical and depend on various factors, and I'd say a bit unpredictable -since you don't know exactly when the kernel is going flush the dirty pages. For instance in Linux (*as you can also read in section 15.3 of Understanding the Linux Kernel*), the dirty pages get written to disk under the following conditions:

- The page cache gets too full and more pages are needed, or the number of dirty pages becomes too large.
- Too much time has elapsed since a page has stayed dirty.
- A process requests all pending changes of a block device or of a particular file to be flushed; it does this by invoking a sync(), fsync(), or fdatasync() system call.

This feature is known to be implemented in HFS+, XFS, Reiser4, ZFS, Btrfs and ext4 filesystems.

Comment: What you describe is a filesystem technique which should be invisible from userspace (and thus does not do what you indicate) on POSIX (file)systems (see [write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/write.html): "If a read() of file data can be proven (by any means) to occur after a write() of the data, it must reflect that write(), **even if the calls are made by different processes**."). Other processes will _not_ see the old data (on POSIX).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I guess my understanding of this filesystem technique was wrong.

Comment: Right, this looks like something else. I vaguely recall now that it was in an interview with RMS that he mentioned this feature, perhaps it was some old arcane system that never lived outside academia... Thanks anyway.