# Reading file that other processes overwrite sometimes

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, gpsd

I wrote a systemd-service/timer that will be update GPS location at using `gpscsv --header 0 -n 1 > /tmp/location` every 10 or 15sec.

when I inspect the text file with `watch -n 1 cat /tmp/location`, there is instance that returns **no text** just before the new data comes.

I'll write other scripts that uses GPS location from the `/tmp/location`,
So How do I make it not vulnerable against these "reading while writing" situation?

Comment: See [rewrite existing file so that it gets replaced by new version atomically, only once fully written](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24395/rewrite-existing-file-so-that-it-gets-replaced-by-new-version-atomically-only-o)

Answer (score 2):

simply don't do that writing to a file!

You've got gps*d*, so use it as a daemon; it's exactly the use case daemons where invented for. Instead of reading from `/tmp/location`, your scripts should just call `gpscsv` themselves, which in turn gets the location from your gpsd.

Comment: The thing I'm building is a small portable device. Using `gpscsv` directly won't work, when the device is inside of the building, So there is a need for remembering last available location.

Comment: But you gave me a good point, I will check whether `gpsd` has some tool that stores last known location. (couldn't find any search results at the time)